# SQL injection question

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I'm doing blackbox testing on a website vulnerable to SQL injection.

I put a `'` on the search bar, and for some reason it didn't show an error.

I put a `'` on the search bar this time with a SQL statement. Now the error shows up.

I tried to guess the query with my SQLi statement: `w%' UNION SELECT ;#`.

It gave me an error, of course.

But now I found out the query: `SELECT * FROM Announcements WHERE ? Announcement LIKE ('%post name here%')`

For some reason when I tried a proper SQLi statement: `w%'); ORDER BY 1-- -` or this `w%') ORDER BY 1 #` It still gives me an error:

```
Could not get data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';ORDER BY 2 #%' OR `announcement_date` LIKE '%w%');ORDER by 2 #%') AND `annou...' at line 1
```

I tried to test some payload from a SQLi payload github which is: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='%username%';`
It gave me an error but this time a column error.

So I tried this `'%test%'` and put it in the search bar and I got a column error:

`Could not get data: Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'`

So I'm thinking, what kind of SQL injection is this? Is my pseudo-query wrong? Is it because I have to do the SQL injection statement inside a `'% %'`? I've tried that but it gave me an error. I put a `'%w w%'` it gave me an error.

Comment: Questions about SQL syntax are off topic on Security SE. I suggest to move the question to SO.

Comment: I don't think we can help. There doesn't seem to be any magic here, you just need to map out what the query is. Keep testing and make sure you are using valid SQL syntax..